# Why does the index for the fibonacci sequence need to be less or equal to 1?

Tags: c, fibonacci

For an assignement, I need to create a code which can display an element `n` in the fibonacci sequence. I have already figured out how to do it, you can find my code below, but I just don't get why the index value needs to be below, or equal to `1`.

Here is my code:

```
int ft_fibonacci(int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
        return (-1);
    if (index <= 1)
        return (index);
    else
        return (ft_fibonacci(index - 1) + ft_fibonacci(index - 2));
}
```

Comment: That's basically the definition of recursion: you have a large problem (`fib(n)` in your case) and you break it down into smaler problems (`fib(n-1)` and `fib(n-2)` in your case) which you solve recursively. **Recursion needs to stop sometime** (in your case when `index <= 1`).

Comment: What if someone calls your function with an invalid argument (like e.g. `-2`)? Also think about the recursive calls... When `index == 2` (for example) and you call `ft_fibonacci(index - 2)`, then the recursive call will have an `index` with value `0`.

Comment: I assume you mean line if (index <= 1): this if covers exactly 2 cases of index: 0 and 1. index lower 0 is covered by the first if. For index 0 you want to return 0, for index 1 you want to return 1, or short: for 0< index <=1 you want to return index.

Comment: You should be aware that this is a perfect example of where recursion should **not** be used. The number of recursive calls to `ft_fibonacci()` will rise exponentially with `index`. Calculating `ft_fibonacci(45)` could take ages. An iterative loop approach would be much faster (e.g., `int a=1, b=1, t; for (int i=0; i<n; i++) t=a,a=b,b+=t; return a;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you should already know, when you write a recursive function, you need to have a base case where you already know the result and can return it, to stop applying recursion.

The numbers of the Fibonacci sequence are: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, [...] and so on. Now, it's pretty clear that the first number is 0. What you have to decide though, is what `index` you want to assign to the first number.

In your function, this `if` represents your base case:

```c
if (index <= 1)
    return (index);
```

This will make the function return `0` for `index = 0`, and `1` for `index = 1`. So, in your case, you are assigning `index = 0` to the first number of the sequence (i.e. you start counting from `0`).

You need `<= 1` because the recursive call is `fib(index -1) + fib(index - 2)`, therefore if you do not have *two* base cases your recursion will never stop. When you reach `index = 2`, your function will call `fib(1) + fib(0)`, and those two will return `1` and `0` respectively, stopping the recursion.

If you wanted to start numbering the Fibonacci numbers from 1, then you would have used:

```c
if (index < 1) // invalid index, should not happen
    return -1;
if (index == 2)
    return 1;
if (index == 1)
    return 0;
```

Or more concisely:

```c
if (index < 1) // invalid index, should not happen
    return -1;
if (index <= 2)
    return index - 1;
```

---

As a rule of thumb, remember that whenever you do not need to deal with negative values (Fibonacci numbers and your indexes cannot be negative), you should use `unsigned` types (in this case `unsigned ft_fibonacci(unsigned index)`). This would also eliminate the need for your error check `if (n < 0)`. You also do not need parentheses around values that are returned.

```c
unsigned ft_fibonacci(unsigned index)
{
    if (index <= 1)
        return index;
    else
        return ft_fibonacci(index - 1) + ft_fibonacci(index - 2);
}
```